# What kind of differential equation problem is this?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

I have a function $f(x,t;k)$, a starting point $x_0$, a gradient $\operatorname{Grad}(f)$, and an equilibrium point $x^*$. I can adjust the parameter $k$ freely, and I know that for any $k$ the process will eventually reach $x^*$.

I want to know which value of $k$ will produce a trajectory that takes me to $x^*$ in the shortest time possible.

What kind of a differential equation problem is this? Is there a canonical solution? Is there a reference somewhere I can check to get more information?

Comment: No, I have to set k at the beginning of the process and then keep it constant. Otherwise, yes, it's a standard control problem.

Comment: What is 'the process' in "for any $k$ the process will eventually reach $x^*$"?

Comment: x starts at x_0 and then follows its gradient every period.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your post, nevermind. What you are looking for is steepest descent, which is a heavily studied topic. Without more knowledge of how k appears, it is hard to give a reference.